# Direct Product of Completions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question is regarding Theorem 8.15, page 62 of Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*. It says that if $A$ is a semi-local ring and $I=m_1\cdots m_r$ be the Jacobson radical of $A$. Then $\hat{A}\cong \hat{A}_{m_1}\times\cdots\times \hat{A}_{m_r}$. The proof given is clear if $\hat{A}_{m_i}$ means $I$-adic completion.

QUESTION: Does $\hat{A}_{m_i}$ mean completion at the maximal ideal $m_i$? If so, then the proof is not quite clear. Usually completion of a local ring means at its maximal ideal, and hence this question. At least it does not seem quite clear to me what is meant there.

Comment: Note that $IA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}=\mathfrak{m}_iA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$, because for $j\neq i$, $\mathfrak{m}_jA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}=A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell Yes I can understand your comment. But then how to finish? Can you make it an answer? This is not a HW or anything like that. Thanks.

Comment: i think it is now clear from your comments. So one can look at it both ways as mentioned in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matsumura means the $\mathfrak{m}_i$-adic completion of this ring (when one says, as does Matsumura, "the completion of the local ring," the max-adic completion is intended). But this doesn't in fact matter, since $I^nA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}=\mathfrak{m}_i^nA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$ for $n\geq 1$, so the $I$-adic completion of $A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$ coincides with its max-adic completion.

Comment: The proof is not unclear if $I$-adic completion is meant. I had a confusion that when one says completion of a local ring, then it is w.r.t maximal ideal. But as you show, it does not matter and that is the comment i made under your answer. Thanks, this was easy, somehow i failed to see it.

Comment: Dear @user114539, Sorry, I misread your original comment, but luckily there's no difference in this case.